# How to get BIVS endorsement on an Irish visa?

Tags: tourist-visas, ireland

I am planning a trip to Ireland to meet my friend (who is pursuing her master's there) and also travel to the UK with her. I want to apply for an Irish short-stay visa, which will be valid for travel onwards to the UK using the BIVS. But I do not understand how to get BIVS endorsement.

I have selected Short Stay (C) multiple-visit visa type with reason for travel as Visit Family/Friend. How to get BIVS? I hold an Indian passport.